# Assign variables imported from csv

Tags: python, arrays, csv, variable-assignment

I have a .csv file which has 3 columns, and looks like this.

```
-10.5,7.79,0
-10.5,8.37,0
-10.5,9.52,0
-10.5,10.10,0
-10.5,11.25,0
```

I want to assign the numbers in the 1st column to the variable array 'x' and the 2nd column to 'y' and 3rd column to 'z'. So that I can plot a 3D figure. My initial code so far is as follows,

```
import csv
ifile  = open('new.csv', "rb")
reader = csv.reader(ifile)

for row in reader:
    writer.writerow(row)

ifile.close()

fig = plt.figure()
axis = fig.gca(projection='3d')
axis.plot_trisurf(x, y, z)
plt.show()
```

But I am not able to assign these numbers in the following variable arrays. So kindly, help me in assigning the datas present in the .csv file  on these variable arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using numpy.

```
import numpy as np
x, y, z = np.loadtxt('new.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this,

```
import csv
ifile = open('new.csv', "rb")
reader = csv.reader(ifile)
x = []
y = []
z = []
for row in reader:
    x.append(float(row[0]))
    y.append(float(row[1]))
    z.append(float(row[2]))

ifile.close()
```

Or a better approach will be like,

```
with open('new.csv', "r") as ifile:
    reader = csv.reader(ifile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[1]))
        z.append(float(row[2]))
```

this will close the file after operation.

Answer (score 1):

Try using my library [pyexcel](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

```
>>> import pyexcel as pe
>>> sheet=pe.load("csv-import.csv")
>>> sheet
Sheet Name: csv-import.csv
+---------+--------+---+
| -10.500 | 7.790  | 0 |
+---------+--------+---+
| -10.500 | 8.370  | 0 |
+---------+--------+---+
| -10.500 | 9.520  | 0 |
+---------+--------+---+
| -10.500 | 10.100 | 0 |
+---------+--------+---+
| -10.500 | 11.250 | 0 |
+---------+--------+---+
>>> sheet.column.format([0,1], float)
>>> sheet.column.format(2, int)
>>> sheet[0,0]
-10.5
>>> type(sheet[0,0])
<type 'float'>
>>> x = sheet.column[0]
>>> y = sheet.column[1]
>>> z = sheet.column[2]
>>> x
[-10.5, -10.5, -10.5, -10.5, -10.5]
>>> y
[7.79, 8.37, 9.52, 10.1, 11.25]
>>> z
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: didnt know about this module. very good for rookies as myself.

Answer (score 0):

Each `row` in `reader` gives you a list of those values. in that for-loop, you could write `(x, y, z) = row`, and then plot your new point.

If you need x to hold a list of all the x's, etc., you could just append, e.g. `Xs.append(x)` in the loop, where `Xs` is initialized to an empty list in advance.